# Push to Heroku failed because of OSError and Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, heroku, web-applications, web-deployment, setup.py

I'm getting this error that's not letting me push to Heroku. Does anyone know what it means and how to fix it?

[image: Error Screen Shot]

Comment: It's all in the error message - you have `xlwings` as dependency which does not support Linux, but the Heroku deployments run on a Linux distro.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I cleaned up the requirements.txt and it works now. :)